# Issue with SpringBoot 3.2.0 upgrade and Swagger documentation generation

Tags: java, swagger, spring-boot-3

I recently upgraded my project to Spring Boot 3.2.0. The project has two modules, with one of them, 'commons-api,' dedicated to generating Swagger documentation from a YAML file. Here are the dependencies used in the 'commons-api' module:

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springdoc-openapi-webmvc-ui.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-databind-nullable.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

And here's the configuration for the OpenAPI generator plugin:

```xml
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
   <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>${openapitools.version}</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <id>contrat-nomenclature</id>
         <phase>generate-sources</phase>
         <goals>
           <goal>generate</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
         <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/contratnomenclature.yaml</inputSpec>
         <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
         <configOptions>
           <sourceFolder>main/java</sourceFolder>
           <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
           <skipDefaultInterface>true</skipDefaultInterface>
           <hideGenerationTimestamp>true</hideGenerationTimestamp>
           <dateLibrary>java</dateLibrary>
           <useTags>true</useTags>
           <useOptional>true</useOptional>
           <useJakartaEe>true</useJakartaEe>
           <useSpringBoot3>true</useSpringBoot3>
       </configOptions>
                  
      
     <modelPackage>${project.groupId}....model</modelPackage>
     <apiPackage>${project.groupId}....api</apiPackage>
       ...
     </configuration>
   </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

The generation process seems to work fine; both controller interfaces and DTO classes are generated successfully. However, in the 'api-nomenclature' module, when implementing an interface like this:

```java
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class MenuController implements MenuApi {
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<List<Menu>> getAllMenus(Optional<String> q, Optional<Integer> page, Optional<@Min(1) @Max(50) Integer> size, Optional<Boolean> full, Optional<String> sort) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(menuService.getAllMenus(q, page, size, full, sort), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

For example, the method getAllMenus is defined in the interface MenuApi:

```java
@Operation(
    operationId = "getAllMenus",
    summary = "Retrieve all menus",
    description = "Retrieve all menus",
    tags = { "Menu" },
    responses = {
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Successful operation", content = {
            @Content(mediaType = "application/json", array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(implementation = Menu.class)))
        }),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Invalid status value"),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "Menu not found")
    }
)
@RequestMapping(
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    value = "/nomenclature/menu",
    produces = { "application/json" }
)
    ResponseEntity<List<Menu>> getAllMenus(
        @Parameter(name = "q", description = "Terme pour filter sur le nom", in = ParameterIn.QUERY) @Valid @RequestParam(value = "q", required = false) Optional<String> q,
        @Parameter(name = "page", description = "Numéro de la page", in = ParameterIn.QUERY) @Valid @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Optional<Integer> page,
        @Parameter(name = "size", description = "Nombre d'éléments par page", in = ParameterIn.QUERY) @Valid @RequestParam(value = "size", required = false, defaultValue = "20") Optional<@Min(1) @Max(50) Integer> size,
        @Parameter(name = "full", description = "Retourne la propriete et les sous éléments", in = ParameterIn.QUERY) @Valid @RequestParam(value = "full", required = false) Optional<Boolean> full,
        @Parameter(name = "sort", description = "Tri", in = ParameterIn.QUERY) @Valid @RequestParam(value = "sort", required = false) Optional<String> sort
    );
```

Upon executing the curl request:

```bash
curl -X 'GET' 'http://localhost:8081/api/v1/nomenclature/menu' -H 'accept: application/json'
```

I encounter the following error: **jakarta.validation.ConstraintDeclarationException**

> jakarta.validation.ConstraintDeclarationException: HV000151: A method
> overriding another method must not redefine the parameter constraint
> configuration, but method MenuController#getAllMenus(Optional,
> Optional, Optional, Optional, Optional) redefines the configuration of
> MenuApi#getAllMenus(Optional, Optional, Optional, Optional, Optional).

Any help or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is copying the parameter annotations to the overridden method an option? If not, you could try making a `default` method calling another method and override that.

Comment: I have tried this option by copying all the annotations as in the interface, but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Do you get the same error when copying the annotations? Make sure you exactly copy the signature with all annotations and also include the method annotations. Alternatively, try removing the `@Min(1) @Max(50)` from `size`.

Comment: We had the same problem. Copying resp. adding the validation annotions to the interface could solve the problem, but it is ugly and was not necessary with SpringBoot < 3.2 :(

Comment: In previous versions of Spring Boot before 3.2, I didn't have any issues. Following your advice by copying the validation annotations or creating a default method resolves the problem. However, since it's an auto-generated interface, every time I compile the 'commons-api' module, I lose the added code in the interface.

Comment: I found solution. Juste adding ```<useBeanValidation>false<useBeanValidation>``` in configOptions. https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/spring/